# Spark executor configuration priority

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I saw a Spark submit command with following parameters

```
spark-submit --class ${my_class} \
         --master yarn \
         --deploy-mode cluster \
         --executor-cores 2 \                        <--- executor cores
         --driver-cores 2\                           <--- driver cores
         --num-executors 12 \                        <--- number of executors 
         --files hdfs:///blah.xml \
               --conf spark.executor.instances=15 \  <--- number of executors again?
               --conf spark.executor.cores=4 \       <--- driver cores again?
               --conf spark.driver.cores=4 \         <--- executor cores again?
```

It seems like there can have multiple ways to set up core number and instance number for executor and driver node, just wondering, in above setting which way take priority and overwrite the other one? The `--` parameter or `conf` parameter? Eventually how many cores and instances are given to the spark job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration are picked up depending upon the order of preference.

Priority wise , config defined in application through set() gets the highest priority.
Second priority is given to spark-submit parameters and then the next priority is given to default config parameters.

`--executor-cores 2 \                        <--- executor cores
         --driver-cores 2\                           <--- driver cores
         --num-executors 12 \                        <--- number of executors`

The above configuration will take priority over --conf parameters as these properties are used to override the default conf priorities.